# How to use file_get_contents to find 'a' and click 'a' to get inner contents

Tags: php, ajax, web-crawler

I am making a crawler to fetch data from pakwheels.com, I was able to fetch data from this website from this code

```
<?php 

    for ($y = 1; $y <= 5; $y++) {
        $pakwheels = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $y . '');
        $file2 = 'pakwheels.txt';
        file_put_contents($file2 , $pakwheels, FILE_APPEND);
    } 

?>
```

But requirement changed and now I want to first get the contents from 
http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search  which I am already doing. The problem is that I want a logic that when I get contents from first page then it will click on the **href a** links of the ads(title) listed in listview and use file get contents to save the whole content of the ads then return back on home page i.e  http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search?page=1 and retrieve the second ad and so on.

I am also doing ajax a.clicked function but i am not able to achieve the result.

If you want more information on this. I will provide those as well.

[image: Home Page] [image: ads page]

Comment: To point you in some kind of direction, without giving you a fleshed out answer. You could find the link you want, extract the URL, and then use CURL or whatever to get the contents of that page and do what you want with it. Bear in mind, you won't be able to use JavaScript powered functionality on these pages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
for ($y = 1; $y <= 5; $y++) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $y);
    $searchResults = curl_exec($ch);

    // save $searchResults here to a file or use DOMDocument to filter what you need

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($searchResults);
    $links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($links as $link) {
        if($link->getAttribute('class') === 'car-name') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pakwheels.com' . $link->getAttribute('href'));
            $details = curl_exec($ch);

            // save $details here to a file or use DOMDocument to filter what you need

        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

If you need further explanations on this, feel free to ask ;-)

Comment: Thanks bro, but I don't understand what this code is doing. can you please explain me

Comment: I loop (just as you do) 5 times over the following: First use cURL (google it) to get the source of the search results then we need to get all links (you said you want the informations of each "ad"), what we use DOMDocument for. The links to the cars all have the class "car-name" so we use this as indicator if it's the link we need. After this we just use cURL again to get the content of the single car information pages :-)

Comment: Thanks Bro, can you please tell me can I apply this code for another website like , olx.com.pk/cars and for carmudi.pk/cars